# How to use JSON for an iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, json, weather

I am trying to make an weather app, I found a great JSON weather API online. I am using

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: absoluteURL]];
NSError * error;
NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data //1
  options: kNilOptions 
  error: & error
];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"location: %@", [json objectForKey: @"status"]]);
```

to get the data, but it wont work, the log returns `(null)`. Can someone plase explain to  me how I can get the strings and values of the JSON file? Thanks!

Comment: What is in the 'error'? Have you done any basic debugging?

Comment: @Wain The error is that I want to get the weather status and not (null) :) I like to shoe the weather status in the log, but instead of e.g. cloudy I get (null) I added the weather, so you can take a look how it is formatted.

Comment: The error attribute you pass in the JSONObjectWithData call. Print it in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Change your code from line 3 (including) to:

```
NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *meta = json[@"objects"];

for (NSDictionary *aDict in meta) {
    NSDictionary *location = aDict[@"location"];
    NSLog(@"%@", location);
}
```

This `NSLog()`s all the locations in your `JSON response`.

If you want the `city` and `country` only once you can do the following:

```
NSDictionary *location = json[@"objects"][0][@"location"];
NSString *country = location[@"country"];
NSString *locality = location[@"locality"];

NSLog(@"country: %@", country);
NSLog(@"locality: %@", locality);
```

**Output:**

> country: Germany
>   locality: Hauzenberg

Comment: @HSA The location Log is (null), but the json Log ( NSLog(@"%@", json) ) is not (nil) it shows the whole JSON script, so I think that there is something wrong with the "scanning thing"

Comment: @HSA OK, take your time, please check the API URL I added to the Post, so you can see the formation!

Answer (score 0):

There is no element "status" in the root of your JSON. The json object will contain exactly same hierarchy as your JSON. In your case, it'll look like this:

```
root (dictionary)
  |
  -- "objects": (array)
        |
        -- (dictionary)
              |
              -- "sources" (array) 
              -- "weather" (dictionary)
...
```

You get the idea.

Try this:

```
for (NSDictionary *object in json[@"objects"])
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"location: %@", object[@"weather"][@"status"]]);
}
```

Comment: @Maroux OK, it works, but the JSON script has 11 statuses, I only need the first one, is there a way to get the 11 different statues as 11 strings?